# AWS S3 API List Object by Key Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to list all objects with a certain last modified date in a directory within my S3 bucket using the aws s3api. I have the following:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket 's3://my-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3' --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `2023-01-08`)].Key'
```

This fails due to the forward slashes in the path not being allowed. I believe I need to add the path to directory using a key value but can't find an example anywhere of how to do it. Can somebody please help?

Comment: `s3://my-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3` is not a bucket; `my-bucket` is the bucket. `dir1/dir2/dir3/` is a key prefix, so use `--bucket mybucket --prefix dir1/dir2/dir3/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the bucket name and S3 object key prefix independently, for example:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
    --bucket my-bucket \
    --prefix dir1/dir2/dir3/ \
    --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `2023-01-08`)].Key'
```